# Servir una imagen desde Servlet 3.0 contentType="multipart/form-data"

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets, formdata

Saludos comunidad!
Planteo el siguiente problema, dispongo de una imagen en una **BBDD** (formato `bytea[]`) y deseo servir una respuesta para mostrar dicha imagen en mi HTML. No dispongo de rutas o directorios, tan solo de la imagen en la BBDD. 
Queda algo como esto:

> cUpload.dameFoto() // devuelve mi imagen en formato inputStream.

He probado a cambiar el **ContentType** con formato imagen `"imagen/jpg"` pero no logro sacar la salida en mi **javascript** . Gracias de antemano por vuestra colaboración

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){      

        OutputStream out;
        BufferedImage bI;
        int nRead;          
        InputStream is;


    try {                                                   

        response.setContentType("multipart/form-data");         

        out = response.getOutputStream();

        is = cUpload.dameFoto();

        bI = ImageIO.read(is);
        ImageIO.write(bI, "png", out);


    } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
        System.err.println("Error en la respuesta de salida uploadServlet: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

}

Comment: Ya intentaste con *`image/png`*? y al final `out.flush()`?

Answer (score 0):

Si no vas a utilizar las capaciades de conversión de ImageIO, por ejemplo convertir de jpg a gif, etc, sería mejor que trates el InputStream como binario y lo escribas como binario también:

```
int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(c);
}
```

Con ImageIO se te va a complicar si después deseas usar otros formatos.

Usa el tipo MIME `image/png` ó `image/jpeg` dependiendo del tipo de imagen que quieras usar. Llama out.flush() para terminar de enviar todo el contenido de la imágen.

Para mostrar la imagen en tu HTML necesitas usar el URL que descarga la imágen en tu `<img ...` :

`<img src="http://servidor.com/servlet-de-imagenes/foto.png" ...`

para darle nombre a tu imágen agrega el encabezado (http header):

`Content-Disposition: filename="foto.png"`

En el servlet:

`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + nombreDeArchivo);`

Comment: he probado tu solución y no reporta error en el envío pero no logro entrar en el success el ajax. Mi metodo jquery en cliente se realiza asi:

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  //Variables
   var datas = new FormData(); 
   var img2 = getBase64Image(img);     
  datas.append('imagen', img2);


  $.ajax({
   url: '/PruebaJEE/uploadServlet',
   type: 'POST',   
   contentType: 'image/png',         
         enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   data: datas,  
   success: function(respuesta){     
    alert("Entramos");             
         }
  });  
 });

Comment: Y que pasa cuando pruebas el URL sólo? Sí baja la imagen como descarga y se ve bien?

Comment: El problema es que no llega a enviar la salida al cliente, se queda en el servidor con un mensaje de error:                                       
`11:17:04.869:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/PruebaJEE/uploadServlet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
 at vista.uploadServlet.doPost(uploadServlet.java:56)`